# Why isn’t Middle-earth filled with elves?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, elves, middle-earth

We know Elves do procreate and have children. We know they do have sex. Immortal beings with normal reproduction would fill Middle-earth if left unchecked (like rabbits).

We see Elrond with 3 children in 3500 years which would be unlikely for a human.

I can only think of 3 reasons:

- Reduced sex. Elves have a reduced sexual drive (similar to Vulcan Pon Farr) so that they have intercourse only every couple hundred of years (sad sad sad life).
- Reduced fertility. Elves have sex at the normal rate but it’s really difficult for them to get pregnant so you can literally spend 1000 years trying.
- Contraception. Not so unlikely as some contraception methods are documented going back to B.C. dates.

Is there any canon source as to why there are so few Elves in Middle-earth?

Comment: Elrond is over 6000 years old, not 3500.

Comment: We see Elrond with 3 children in 3500 years which would be unlikely *for a human.*  Moreso due to the being 3000+ (or 6000+) years old part than the 3 children part, I presume.